# Unity3d Gravity issue .Sphere passing through the board

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity

I am making "Marble-board" game using Unity3d with mono-develop(c#).i want to make marbles rolling using gravity.But marble is passing through the board ,when i apply gravity to it.please help to solve my problem

For more specification,
Rigidbody Component of Sphere:  Use Gravity : true
                                Is Kinematic :false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Rigibody is needed for physics - ie. the sphere should have a rigidbody if you want to use a built-in Unity's gravity. The ground should only have a collider  ↓

All objects need Colliders to be able to detect collision. Make sure both objects have Colliders and the `isTriggered` is false (*unless you handle collisions with scripts*).

So, in a simple setup like this

[image]

The `Plane`s properties:

[image]

And the `Sphere`'s properties:

[image]

So when the `Sphere` drops onto the `Plane` it **does not** go through.

Comment: Thanks,@me how .Is Trigger property of my plane was on :) its done now. and thanks for such a detail explanation.

Comment: @RenukaDevganiya no problem. If `IsTrigger` is ticked it pretty much means you want to handle the collision using `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` by script :)